# What is the purpose of std::hash and/or boost::hash ?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, stdhash

Why providing an hash function without specifing any implementation of reference and also without specifying the algorithm of reference ( md5, sha256, etc etc ) ?

Also there are similar features for data structures such as the C++ standard-compliant `std::unordered_map/set/multimap/multiset::hash_function`.

So what i don't get is:

- Why providing such undocumented methods
- The implementation details are fundamental for a right use of the hash functions, from a programmer standpoint what is the purpose of these functions
- This function can be linked to a specific algorithm ?

Comment: std::hash and sha/md5 are different things. std::hash is for generating hash codes for things like data structure lookups. it's not meant to be a cryptographic hash function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why providing such undocumented methods

They are not undocumented.

> The implementation details are fundamental for a right use of the hash functions, from a programmer standpoint what is the purpose of these functions

The implementation is unspecified, they are just supposed to be used together with unordered containers. They should be as good a hash function as possible, to effectively distribute elements into buckets. Anything else is unspecified.

Note that user is expected to provide these if using unordered containers with *user defined types*.

> This function can be linked to a specific algorithm ?

Why not?

Comment: "They should be as good a hash function as possible" They "should"? really? When I talk about being undocumented i refer to the implementation details by the way, the only thing that usually matters when dealing with hash functions.

Comment: @user1824407: Not really, unordered containers will work just fine even with the worst possible hash function ever... The quality of the has function does not affect behavior, just performance.

Comment: ok, for data structures, with a good logic, you can avoid this problem, but what about std::hash ? if I need to rely on an hash functions for 10 years or more, and it's implementation is basically compiler-specific and it's likely to change over the time: what is the point of that ?

Comment: @user1824407: They are only supposed to be used to distribute elements into buckets, I fail to see the problem with a compiler specific implementation... Why do you think you need to _rely_ on them?

Comment: i build a database that stores stats about files, each file is represented by its own hash, with this approach from the STL I just can't do this in a reliable way. Each platform will code a different hash, each compiler will compute a different hash and during the years this can only get worst beacause the compilers will update their own implementations.

Comment: @user1824407: Of course you can't! They are **only** supposed to distribute elements into buckets. If you need a hash for something else then create your own implementation over which you have control...

Comment: I think there's confusion about what he's asking. std::hash and boost::hash are not cryptographic hash functions, or wrappers around SHA or MD5. If you look at the documentation, you'll see they are not meant for crypto applications (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash). You need to look at something like OpenSSL.

Comment: @mfanto ok, now i get that, but what about boost ?

Comment: @user1824407: Some thing with _Boost_... You may have luck with the unofficial _Boost.Crypto_ that was lying around somewhere in the _Boost Vault_